# How do I start dnsmasq?

Tags: osx, dnsmasq

I have installed `dnsmasq` but I can't start it:

```
$ dnsmasq

dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 10.0.1.57: Permission denied
$ sudo dnsmasq

dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.54: Address already in use
```

So how do I specify a socket and what address? How do I start it?

Comment: That appears like you are already running a service that listens on port 53, the default for DNS. Check with `netstat` or `lsof`.

Comment: I'd further suggest that you've probably already got `dnsmasq` itself running. Check with `sudo netstat -nap | grep :53`. The usual way of starting `dnsmasq` would be `service dnsmasq start` or on non-Linux systems something like `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq start`.